# how to show ng-model as a date whit it is not null, and show nothing if it is null

Tags: angularjs

I have a textbox like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" ng-model="date | date:'yy-MM-dd'"/>
```

But sometimes the date will be null and it will cause an error: `[ngModel:nonassign]`.  What can i do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `ng-model="date | ..."` because the filter makes this nonassignable which is why you are getting the error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/nonassign

Instead, just use `ng-model="date"`  If you want the date to display with a particular format you may want to use `type="date"` for the input.  You could also use `ng-keyup` to properly format the date in the controller as it is changed.